# NSIS Installer slow on machine with Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: nsis, antivirus

So I've got an issue where our NSIS installers slow down heaps when installing over the top of an existing installation?

It seems to be directly related to Microsoft's Security Essentials and turning off runtime checking causes it to go away, but I've never encountered anything similar with any other installers - so is there a known issue here or should we be doing things differently to avoid this kind of thing?

To give you an idea how slow.. each .EXE takes 10-15 seconds to unpack but on a clean machine or with Security Essentials turned off it takes only a second or two - and this is on the a top of the line core i7 with 12GB of ram.

Only thing I can think of is to copy the exe to a temporary file and then move it over afterwards, but this seems a bit clunky.

Answer (score 0):

-- Outdated answer. Microsoft Defender is kinda good now --

You're gonna hate me.

If you're competent, lose the antivirus.

Antivirus is only needed by those who are unable to keep their machines from getting infected without it.

I ran antivirus for years, and had it legitimately trip only once, on a six month old backup of my mail folder. What's weird is it sat for 6 months before the antivirus caught it. In the meantime, it tripped many times on false positives.

I don't run antivirus anymore and would be glad if I never ran it again.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but telling our customers to 'lose their antivirus' is probably the last thing I would want to do.

Comment: Those who cannot defend themselves by sound practices will pay an outrageous price for machine based defense. As far as I know nothing can be done for them.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider switching to using Microsoft WIX instead, http://wix.sourceforge.net/ It works quite nicely, it's free, and it's supported by Microsoft.  I'm fairly sure that Microsoft is not going to let it interact negatively with their own anti-virus.

The "killer moment" when I switched from nsis, was when one of the nsis uninstallers generated a false positive with microsoft defender.  I then uploaded it to http://virustotal.com , and 5 out of 20 anti-virus scanners flagged it as a trojan.  I'm not sure exactly what nsis uninstaller does to make it prone to false positives, but the idea of one of my not so many potential clients trying tentatively my software and then being told it is a virus fills me with horror!